# Flex and PHP Connection

Tags: php, apache-flex, zend-framework

I am working on a project involving a PHP connection, the UI is developed using flash builder, I have Combo Box and Text Input for users to pick some items and at the same time users can input their details on the Text Input. The app is not generating anything up till now. I need to send data to PHP for PHP to look up into its folder containing some images. I used folder instead of database, the output should be sent back to Flex for it to be saved into another folder and I also want a copy to be saved inside another folder in PHP. Please is there anyone that could be of help?

These are some of the codes used:

```
public function Drop2_disabled(event:Event):void{
    love=="orange"&&"pawpaw"&&"maize";                                             hate=="rice"&&"maize"&&"starch"; 
    if((Drop2.selectedItem=="orange"||"pawpaw"||"maize")&& 
                      (Drop3.selectedItem=="rice"||"maize"||"starch"))
        ValueCommit="{foodVO.love}"
}
```

was now used under the ComboBox to bind foodVO to variable love, this was repeated for the text Input also. My foodVO is an action script file. foodVO was then mapped to my foodVO.Php using Zend server.

The PHP will then use the data sent from the remote object to look up into his own  folder to read the images and then send it back to flex.
(`services-config.xml`)
These are some of the PHP script

```
<?php
class foodVO
{
    public $maize;
    public $rice;
    public $pawpaw;
    public $starch;
    public $orange;
    public function _construct()
    {
        $maize        = $_GET["maize"];
        $rice         = $_GET["rice"];
        $orange       = $_GET["orange"];
        $pawpaw       = $_GET["pawpaw"];
        $this->maize  = "";
        $this->orange = "";
        $this->pawpaw = "";
        $this->starch = "";
    }

}
?><?php
include 'Zend/Amf/Server.php';
include './food.php/services/foodService.php';
// Initialize AMF Server
$server = new Zend_Amf_Server();
$server->setClass("foodService");
$server->setProduction($amf->production);
$server->setClassMap('foodVO', 'foodVO');
// Handle request
echo $server->handle();
?>
```

The `foodservice.php` contains my Imagick operations. 
Please I need help?
Thanks.

Comment: can't speak with much authority with flex but I am familiar with ecma and the `Drop2.selectedItem=="orange"||"pawpaw"||"maize"` test, I don't think it is going to do what you want (I think it will always be true).   I think it would have to be `Drop2.selectedItem=="orange"||Drop2.selectedItem=="pawpaw"||Drop2.selectedItem=="maize"`

Comment: Thanks Orangepill, for the information

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you achieved the connection but in order to send data back and forward between PHP and Flex there is the [ActionScript Message Format extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/amfext). There are also libraries that you can use such as [AmfPHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmfPHP). Zend also has [classes for this - Zend Amf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.amf.html).

Comment: This is an answer, not a comment. ;) Glad I could help.